# Как сделать в Swift чтоб суперкласс не срабатывал

Tags: swift, классы, методы, переопределение

Как сделать в Swift  чтоб суперкласс не срабатывал, а работал только наследованный субкласс? Не судите строго, я новичок в Swift.

```
class X{
 func zi(x:Int, z:Int){
print(x+z)  
 }  
}
class A:X{
 override func zi(x:Int, z:Int) { 
 super.zi(x:x, z:z) 
print("\(x)+\(z)=4")        
 }    
}  
var rr=A()
rr.zi(x:2, z:2) 
4
2+2=4
```

Comment: Что значит "чтоб суперкласс не срабатывал"?

Comment: Обратите внимание, результат показывает как вызванный, субкласс A так и суперкласс Х, просто я рубист, если мы не вызываем в ruby суперкласс, то он и нечего и не покажет на консоле, я вам покажу пример на ruby, также я и хотел и swift.
<pre>  class X def Mymedot(x)
  puts"Cyslo #{x}" 
 end
end 
class A<X
 def Mymedot(x,z) 
  puts "Dva Cysla #{x}+#{z}" 
end
end
var=A.new
var.Mymedot(2,2) <code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убери `super.zi(x:x, z:z)` и функция из суперкласса не будет срабатывать. Этим вызовом ты обращаешься напрямую к функции суперкласса.